# Regarding executable jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have developed an application and mostly it is a `Swing` based application. I have made the executable `JAR` of the whole project. Now when I click that `JAR` it gets executed and my project starts and the `Swing` window shows up as usual. But when I try to execute that same executable `JAR` on another system it doesn't get executed. Please advise how to solve this..!!

The reason that might be that the JRE may also not be installed on his system or the class path was not set..! Please advise how to execute the same JAR on his system too.

Comment: Run the Jar from the command line of the other computer using `java -jar the.jar` and copy/paste the output.

Comment: I think you need to update the environment of JRE, there may be 1.5 on the client side and you may have compiled in 1.6 and placed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to:

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net
http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net

these wraps your jar into an executable,which makes easier to distribute your app,taking care of things as setting the classpath and installing the JVM if not present.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with eclipse? Maybe the other system doesn't have the `JRE7`. If this is the case, you have following possibilities:

1. Update the `JRE` on the other system
2. Create a new project in eclipse and select `JavaSE-1.6` at "Use an execution environment JRE"

This compiles your project JRE6 compatible. However, you have to put more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is missing some details.

Please, specify output that you get when running your application on your friend's machine.

Otherwise it is hard to advice something.

More details are also welcome: jdk/jre version, OS version, build scripts, etc.

Comment: @Borys86..I got the answer I need to set the path and classpath manually from command window